# Why Avdi Grimm's database_cleaner example doesn't work anymore right now in rails 4.2.4?

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

I'm not quite sure what is the exact problem, but the example of database_cleaner usage suggested by Avdi Grimm doesn't seem to work anymore with now, instead the example shown in database_cleaner README works. Both examples already set the transactional fixture to false.

Following is Avdi Grimm's example taken from [his blog](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # added here for completeness
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false 

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

And following is the working example shown in database_cleaner [README](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = example.metadata[:js] ? :truncation : :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

The only thing that is different is the truncation strategy setting.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC The second one will use truncation for any non-nil/false value of the :js tag, the first one will only use truncation if the :js tag === true.

Comment: even if I changed the `:js => true` to `:js` on the first one, it's still doesn't work.